# Issue ElasticBeanStalk/Tomcat war deploy Using EB CLI 3.4.5 (Python 2.7.6)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Set up:
src/main/webapp/.ebextensions has the following:

```
container_commands:
      replace-config:
        command: cp src/main/webapp/.ebextensions/server.xml /etc/tomcat8/server.xml
```

.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml has the following:

```
deploy:
      artifact: target/service.war
```

When I try to deploy the war file using eb-cli, I get

```
cannot stat 'src/main/webapp/.ebextensions/server.xml': No such file or directory
```

and the deploy fails/terminates. Any pointers on this is appreciated.

Comment: might be an issue with git. The CLI does some git command to get the version label/description.

Comment: What happens if you do: `eb deploy --label vX.X --message "My App"`

Comment: As you can notice, I'm deploying a built 'war' file, not sure if this is git issue, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I noticed. Re-read my first comment. Even though you are not deploying a git commit, the CLI still does some git commands (if you have a git project).

Comment: ok, I tried `eb deploy --label ebcli-test --message "Testing now"` and it gave the same error.

Comment: OK. Can you run it with --debug?

Comment: `ERROR: [Instance: XXXXX] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: cp: cannot stat 'src/main/webapp/.ebextensions/server.xml': No such file or directory.
container_command replace-config in .ebextensions/server-update.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'XXXXX'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.`

Comment: OK, so the code is getting to the instance, but the instance is erroring out trying to deploy your war. Are you sure that file is in your war?

Comment: Yes, the file is in a) I manually checked in the war i'm building b) also I see this in AWS logs: `inflating: /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/.ebextensions/server.xml` c) I manually checked in that location on the instance, /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT/.ebextensions/server.xml

Comment: `src/main/webapp/.ebextensions/server.xml` != `ROOT/.ebextensions/server.xml`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It does seem eb-cli is a bit weird with git. Finally I did eb-init from target folder (which is not in git) and kept server.xml location as `.ebextensions/server.xml` and it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Nick Humrich for helping me debug. My final solution was to `eb init` from target folder (which is not in git) and keeping server.xml path as `.ebextensions/server.xml`.